# why does the sdo_arc_desify code doesnt work for my oracle database table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to update a table with a densified arc geometry:

```sql
update aip_radiofrequencyarea 
set extent_arc = SDO_GEOM.SDO_ARC_DENSIFY(
                   extent,
                   MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ARRAY(
                     MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('X',3460000,3475000,0.005),
                     MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('Y',5500000,5635000,0.005)
                   ),
                   MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('Z',0, 1000, 0.005),
                   'ARC_TOLERANCE=0.005'
                 );
```

This is the error message I get:

```
SQL-Fehler: ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number of Arguments in 'SDO_ARC_DENSIFY'
06553. 00000 -  "PLS-%s: %s"
*Cause:    SQL compilation failed because of an illegal reference to a
           PL/SQL unit.
*Action:   If the PL/SQL error message does not provide a workaround, then
           try the SQL statement as a top-level call as the appropriate user
           with the appropriate privileges.
```

Does somebody know why that is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have put `MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('Z',0, 1000, 0.005)` as the third argument of `SDO_ARC_DENSIFY` when it should be an element of the `SDO_DIM_ARRAY`:

```sql
update aip_radiofrequencyarea 
set extent_arc = SDO_GEOM.SDO_ARC_DENSIFY(
                   extent,
                   MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ARRAY(
                     MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('X',3460000,3475000,0.005),
                     MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('Y',5500000,5635000,0.005),
                     MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('Z',0, 1000, 0.005)
                   ),
                   'ARC_TOLERANCE=0.005'
                 );
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MTUl7i2W)

Comment: Thank you very much! Cant belive i missed that